# User cannot install to device with android 4.0.4 even though app supports APIs 3 - 16

Tags: android

I have a user with Motorola XT910 with android 4.0.4 reported he is unable to download my application from the Google Play Store.  The error states the device is not compatible with the current version; however, my application supports APIs 3 - 16 which should include android 4.0.4.

I currently have API 16 and SDK Tools r20, and from the android revision history (http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/platforms.html) I can see API 15 revision 3 is needed for Android 4.0.4.  I haven't been able to download revision 3 as it doesn't show up in the SDK Manager, but shouldn't API 16 cover that?  or am I making a wrong assumption?

Do I need to download revision 3 of the API 15 or does having API 16 covers it?
If it's needed, what can I do so that this particular revision shows up in the SDK Manager?  Or is it possible to download elsewhere without using the SDK manager.

Comment: What does your `minSdkVersion` and `maxSdkVersion` specify in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Possible silly question since you are talking about a Motorola device, but do you happen to have copy protection enabled for your app in the Play Console?  If so, you'll see issues like the one you describe with devices that don't pass Google's CTS.  Hard to fathom any Motorola device not passing the CTS though...

Comment: **t0mm13b:**
Min is 3, Max is 16.

**@Nick**
Yes, it is set to ON, and that may explain why I've only received a couple of complaints and not a lot.
What is the recommended way to go about this?
I guess I'll set it to OFF since my app is free anyway and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Its a deprecated feature so I personally always disable it and honestly, even if it were a paid app, the copy protection is laughably ineffective.

Comment: **@Nick**, that did the trick, thanks.  If you want add your previous comments as an answer so I can accept it as a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was resolved based on Nick's input above.
The problem was caused by the Copy Protection setting in the Play Console for the app.  To resolve simply set this to OFF and the problem will be resolved.
NOTE: You may need to wait a couple of hours for the setting change to take effect and reflect on the Google Play Store.